# Raising an error for slug unique in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following model in models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

for which i use a generic view:

```
class QuestionCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ['title', 'text']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        slug = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])
        if Question.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
             form.add_error("title","This Question already exist")
             return self.form_invalid(form)
```

The idea is to automatically create a slug from the users title to use for url, is this approach okay if i want to do this? Is the way i added the error message correct?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Understandable, but how can i now get the code i posted to make a new topic? That is allowed so far i could read

Comment: Open the [edit history](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/154564/revisions) and copy the code from there.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I didn't realize that you did not want to save the form to the database. It's obvious now, sorry. So this answer no longer applies. But why don't you try to save the actual Question object instead?

---

This should work, and there's no reason to change if you validated that it does work with tests.

However it would be more Pythonic to actually try saving (without `commit=False`), then catching the resulting [django.db.IntegrityError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError) exception. See [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) to understand why this is more Pythonic. The happy path will be faster too since you only need to call the database once.

Comment: i simply remove the whole `save()`, given there is no need to save the form to validate if slug exist. I also added some additional options.